# DatePicker shows wrong value of month

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I have a problem in `DatePicker` in android when I use `getMonth()` method then it will return a wrong value.

For example:

```
DatePicker datepicker=new DatePicker();

int day=date.getDayOfMonth();
int month=date.getMonth();
int year=date.getYear();

t.setText(""+day+" / "+month+" / "+year);
```

If I will select aug 06 1987 then it will return 6/7/1987

I think it is an error, if not tell me the reason please.

Comment: you can also take code from http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-datepicker.html It is very easy. just follow the steps given. It works.

Answer (score 86):

As described in the [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html#Date%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), months are indexed starting at 0. This means August is month 8, or index 7, thus giving you the correct result.

It is a simple matter of adding 1 to the index returned by the API to get the traditional one-indexed month.

Although this behavior may seem strange, it is consistent with the java.util.Calendar class (although it is *not* consistent with joda.time.DateTime).

Comment: If you have an array with the names of the months, you want the months to be zero indexed to match with this array. The days don't have this problem, a number is all anyone expects.

Answer (score 46):

In Android, when you select a date from the date picker, it starts counting the months from 0. So, this means that the returned month value is always month−1.

For example, if you select August (the 8th month), then it returns 8−1=7.

This means that what you need to do is add 1 to the month value that you get from the DatePicker.

You can do that this way:

```
DatePicker datepicker = new DatePicker();

int day   = date.getDayOfMonth();
int month = date.getMonth()+1;  // here I added 1 to the month
int year  = date.getYear();

t.setText(day+" / "+month+" / "+year);
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason I can think of why this has been in Java util is as follows:

Consider days from Jan 1st to Jan 31st.

A day like 22nd January can be considered as **0 month + 22 days** of that year.
Whereas 15th February can be stated as: **1 month + 15 days** of that year.

Likewise 10th December can be stated as: **11 months + 10 days** of that year.

Hence Jan-Dec is referred as 0-11.

Answer (score 2):

There is no error in this. Counting of months in the Calendar class is zero based. [see this.](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#AUGUST)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code:

```
String mes = this.datepicker.getMonth()/10==0?("0"+this.datepicker.getMonth()): 
String.valueOf(this.datepicker.getMonth());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (month >= 0){
   month = month+1;
 }
 yourTextArea.setText(dayOfMonth+" / "+month+" / "+year);
```

It worked for me.
Hope it would also work for you.
Eat sleep code repeat

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete solution in Kotlin

```
private var mYear = 0
private var mMonth:Int = 0
private var mDay:Int = 0
private var updateDate: String = ""
```

Show Datepicker dialog

```
val c: Calendar  = Calendar.getInstance();
mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
val datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog(
     requireContext(),
     OnDateSetListener { view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ->
          val date = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse("$dayOfMonth/$monthOfYear/$year")
          updateDate = "$dayOfMonth/${monthOfYear+1}/$year"
          }, mYear, mMonth, mDay)
datePickerDialog.show()
```