# DatePicker showing month value starting from 0

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker

I am using two `datepickers` one for `start date` and one for `end date` in one `activity` and whenever I select a month,it shows the wrong number. I tried adding `+1` to the month value but since there are two `datepickers` and we have to skip the days before the `start date` for selection so it is not working. The code is given below :

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year,
                month, day);
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user

        cval_from.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    }
}

public static class ToDatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    // Calendar startDateCalendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        String getfromdate = cval_from.getText().toString().trim();
        String getfrom[] = getfromdate.split("/");
        int year, month, day;
        year = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[2]);
        month = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[1]);
        day = Integer.parseInt(getfrom[0]);
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(year, month, day + 1);
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
        return datePickerDialog;
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        cval_to.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
    }

}
```

Here,`cval_from` is the `start date` and `cval_to` is the `end date`,now if I add `month+1` in `cval_from` the `cval_to` selection of dates starts from the next month. For example if I select `26/1/2018` for `cval_from`,I have to select `cval_to` from `27/1/2018` onwards. The whole month is skipped.

Can anyone help?

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467816/datepicker-shows-wrong-value-of-month

Comment: @jitendrapurohit, already seen. But it didn't help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener.html) month ranges from 0-11.

So you need to increment it by 1.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    int selectedMonth = month+1;
    cval_to.setText(day + "/" + selectedMonth + "/" + year);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use two date picker at different click when you use for start date send date in method which you want to set initially in the DatePicker as well as end date and call this method at Click

```
void selectDate(int mDay ,int mMonth,int mYear) {

    DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,R.style.mydatetheame,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                    tv_date.setText((monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + dayOfMonth + "/" + year);

                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();

}
```

and of course, you will get a correct month by this method.